# How do I create the expected output in this Arithmetic Operators problem on HackerRank?

Tags: python, function, loops, iteration

I am a beginner in Python 3 and I am trying to practice more of my Python 3 skills by trying to solve  HackerRank problems but I am a little stuck on this one problem. I have already written some code but I am having trouble with getting the expected output. Can someone please help?

**The instructions:**

Read two integers from STDIN and print three lines where:

The first line contains the sum of the two numbers.
The second line contains the difference of the two numbers (first - second).
The third line contains the product of the two numbers.

**Output Format**

Print the three lines as explained above.

Sample Input

```
3
2
```

Sample Output

```
5
1
6
```

Here is my code, I created three functions to add, subtract, and multiply the inputted numbers but I need to know how to write some code that will iterate through a list and make the outputted numbers move vertically:

```
def addition(a, b):
    print (a + b)

#Main 
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
addition(a, b)

def subtraction (a, b):
    print (a - b)

#Main 
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
subtraction(a, b)

def multiplication(a, b):
    print (a * b)

#Main 
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
multiplication(a, b)
```

Comment: The instruction is to read two input values and then to output three results. Your code is doing something different. It reads two inputs, outputs one result, then reads two more inputs, outputs one result, and then reads two more inputs, and outputs one result.

Comment: Do you know a way that I could get my code to output the sum, the difference, and the product of the inputted values altogether in a vertical line?

Comment: Sure, but I would hope you would find it out yourself. In what I describe, it is clear that you are doing too much. Eliminate what the code should not do, so that it matches the expected behaviour. Ask yourself: how many times am I supposed to read input; How many times am I doing it? How can I align that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need to use functions for these simple, built-in tasks.

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
print(a+b)
print(a-b)
print(a*b)
```

This will work too.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know why I didn't think of that! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not read the input multiple times. Read only once and then perform the operations

```
def addition(a, b):
    print (a + b)

#Main 
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
addition(a, b)

def subtraction (a, b):
    print (a - b)

subtraction(a, b)

def multiplication(a, b):
    print (a * b)

multiplication(a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to iterate through a list of numbers. The evaluator will run for code several times and do that vertical formatting for you. The following should suffice.

You don't need to take the input multiple times. Just store it once and call the three functions you have written.

```py
def addition(a, b):
    print (a + b)

def subtraction (a, b):
    print (a - b)

def multiplication(a, b):
    print (a * b)

#Main 
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
## Note this
addition(a, b)
subtraction (a, b)
multiplication(a, b)
```

The print function in python by default prints in different lines and the last three lines of your code makes sure that is how it is printed. 
However, for your own testing (so that you don't have to move your code around too much) you can try the following:

```py
def addition(a, b):
    print (a + b)

def subtraction (a, b):
    print (a - b)

def multiplication(a, b):
    print (a * b)

def getOutput(a,b):
    #a = int(input())
    #b = int(input())
    addition(a, b)
    subtraction (a, b)
    multiplication(a, b)

listA=[1,2,3,45,9]
listB=[2,3,4,70,1]
for i in range(len(listA)):
   getOutput(listA[i],listB[i])
```

You will have to however submit code in the format of the first code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
def addition(a, b):
    print (a + b)

def subtraction (a, b):
    print (a - b)

def multiplication(a, b):
    print (a * b)


a = int(input())
b = int(input())
addition(a, b)
subtraction(a, b)
multiplication(a, b)
```

Input:

```
3
2
```

Output:

```
5
1
6
```